# Conda returns 'Following specifications found to be incompatible with each other' for all install/update commands

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, version, conda

I get the classic `The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other` followed by a long list of packages for almost every conda command including:

```
conda update --all
conda install pkgName
```

Rendering conda basically useless. Even now to do a fresh install I can't run the initial command `conda install anaconda-clean` without this error

Versions: MacOS Big Sur 11.6
Python 3.8.8
conda 4.10.3
Anaconda 2021.05

Comment: Generally, this problem can be avoided by using multiple environments rather than trying to install everything in one place. Also, some users favor minimal **base** installations, such as Miniconda or Miniforge (I highly recommend [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge)), which helps mitigate against such broken or unchangeable **base** situations.

Comment: Thanks - anaconda-clean ran in an environment, but when I try to fully remove Anaconda - the commands `rm -rf ~/anaconda3` and `sudo rm -rf /opt/anaconda3` have no effect after this, either in the environment just created, or in BASE

Comment: What does "*have no effect*" mean? Also, you'll likely need to clean out `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` of any Conda references, then restart the terminal.

Comment: `which python` tells me conda etc are all running from `/opt/anaconda3`, and when I try to remove this, nothing happens.  I have read/write permissions on the file, and have restarted terminal & mac several times.  Any advice?

Comment: I think I was suppressing output with -rf.  `rm -r /anaconda3` worked as it was a directory - I now have Miniconda up and running.  Thanks merv!